# Does xdotool have a log?

Tags: xdotool, password-store

I'm using `xdotool` to securely type out a password (as opposed to using the clipboard) from a password manager (`pass`) and I'm wondering if xdotool has a log somewhere, which would obviously make it insecure.

So it there a log, or any other potential insecurity that anyone else can see?

For reference, this is what I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
from time import sleep

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    delay = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    delay = 3

data = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
sleep(delay)
subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'type', '--clearmodifiers', data])
```

Comment: Do you really have to provide the password as keyboard input at the X level? There's usually a better way, like getting the program to interface with the password manager directly or to read from a terminal.

Comment: That sounds great, but I have no idea about how I would do it at a lower level. How can you get a web browser to read from the output of a process?

Comment: Web browsers typically do have interfaces to password managers. For example Firefox and Chrome can interface with Gnome-keyring. It might take some effort if the password needs to be typed in a field that isn't marked as password.

Comment: The `xdotool` command line (including password) will briefly be visible to other processes on the system. Unfortunately I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: @Gilles One use case: Host a has just been booted and is now displaying a login screen. Home directories are encrypted using ecryptfs. Host b somehow knows the password and wants to type it in on the login screen on host a. Host b can ssh to host a and run xdotool (using key based authentication because sshd has password authentication turned off). Could that use case be solved without using xdotool?

Comment: @kasperd Good point. I guess I'll have to rethink it. There may be a python library that does what `xdotool` does, in which case the typing would all be part of the python process

Comment: @texasflood Please let me know If you find a solution to that.

Comment: @kasperd Sure, do you think the Python library solution would work, before I go hunting for one?

Comment: @texasflood I am sure that could work. What I don't know is how much of what you need will already have been implemented, and how much you will need to implement yourself.

Comment: @kasperd Think I found a solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262310/simulate-keypress-in-a-linux-c-console-application/14083761#14083761). Just install `libxdo3` instead of `libxdo2` and `xdo_keysequence` to `xdo_send_keysequence_window`

Comment: @kasperd That's a completely different use case, but not a convincing one either: why would you simulate typing at a login screen instead of just doing the login, running `ecryptfs-mount-private` from the SSH session?

Comment: @Gilles Because the goal is to end up with the user being logged into Gnome on host a.

Comment: @kasperd Which does not require typing into the display manager. Run `startx`.

Comment: @Gilles That's not going to grant the user the privileges associated with a local login such as access to use audio devices. I am not even sure the user can run `startx` without having those privileges in the first place. Besides if `startx` did work it would start a second X server rather than using the one already running.

Comment: @kasperd I've found a much simpler solution, which you can see in my revised answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is no `xdotool` log as far as I am aware, but as kasperd pointed out, running `xdotool` with the password as an argument is clearly insecure. But we may pass in the password through a pipe to avoid it showing up in the output of `ps aux`.

```
echo -n "$pass" | xdotool type --clearmodifiers --file -
```

By default (in `bash`), the builtin version of echo is used, which does not execute as it's own process, so doesn't show up in `ps`. You can run `builtin echo` if you're not sure which version will be used.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 there is no mention of `--file` in the man page. But it turns out to be working anyways.

Comment: @kasperd I know - that's why it took me so long to discover this possibility. I may submit a patch to `xdotool` to add this information to the man page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `xdotool` using Python's `subprocess.call()`  you should directly interface with the library underlying `xdotool`: `libxdo`.

The bindings for Python are available in [`python-libxdo`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libxdo/) and allows you to "type" the password from within Python without ever showing up in `ps aux`, as there is no separate process invoked.